How do I make python give me the right solutions for a function and change the format of the zeros based on the sign?
I am trying to make a quadratic formula calculator. Everything seems fine, however, when I put in some functions, like x^2-2x+1 and x^2+2x+1, it gives me the same zeroes for them when they have different solutions. Another issue I encounter is that at the end of the code, the format_solution(root), I want it to make it so that it changes format depending on the sign. For example, if the zero is (x - 1), I don't want it to put (x + -1) and instead just (x - 1); I cannot figure out how to do that.
import math
import cmath

print('Follow this format: Ax^2 + Bx + C')

a = float(input('Enter A: '))
b = float(input('Enter B: '))
c = float(input('Enter C: '))

#Functions

def qfpositive(a, b, c):
  return(-abs(b)+cmath.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a

def qfnegative(a, b, c):
  return(-abs(b)-cmath.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a

def format_solution(root):
  if root.real == 0:

    return f'(x {root.real})'
      # Root is a real number
  if root.real > 0:
    return f'(x + {root.real})'
  elif root.real < 0:
    return f'(x {root.real})'
  elif root.imag > 0:
      # Root has a positive imaginary part
      return f'(x {root.real} + {root.imag}i)'
  else:
      # Root has a negative imaginary part
      return f'(x {root.real} - {abs(root.imag)}i)'

x1 = qfpositive(a, b, c)
x2 = qfnegative(a, b, c)

print(format_solution(x1))
print(format_solution(x2))

I tried to put in the following code
if root.real > 0:
    return f'(x + {root.real})'
  elif root.real < 0:
    return f'(x {root.real})'

This way, if the format of the zero was positive, it output (x + #). If the format of the zero was negative, it would give me (x - #) and not (x + -#).

Why are you taking the absolute value of b?

And why are you assuming that the solution is purely real in the cases where you assume that?

A better implementation would be to find your discriminant first. The discriminant is the value of b^2 - 4ac. Then check if it's negative or not. If it's negative, then its roots are complex and will require cmath library, otherwise it has real roots and will require math library. See an implementation of this here:
import math
import cmath

print('Follow this format: Ax^2 + Bx + C')

a = float(input('Enter A: '))
b = float(input('Enter B: '))
c = float(input('Enter C: '))

#Functions

def discriminant():
    """Return the value of the discriminant"""
    quadratic_discriminant = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
    return quadratic_discriminant


def quadratic_formula():
    """The quadratic formula"""
    d = discriminant()

    # If the discriminant is non-negative, it will have real roots and 
    # will require python's math library.
    if d >= 0:
        x_1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        x_2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

    # If discriminant is negative, it will have complex roots and will 
    # require python's complex math library.
    else:
        x_1 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
        x_2 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

    print(f"\nThe roots are {x_1} and {x_2}\nDiscriminant: {d}")


quadratic_formula()


Thank you for that. However, I still have a question. It returns the roots and not the actual factored form, which is what I am looking for. To achieve that, I tried using the code:
 if x_1, x_2 >= 0:
  print(f"\nThe roots are {x_1} and {x_2}\nFactored form: (x + {x_1}) and (x + {x_2})\nDiscriminant: {d}")

elif x_1, x_2 < 0:
  print(f"\nThe roots are {x_1} and {x_2}\nFactored form: (x {x_1}) and (x {x_2})\nDiscriminant: {d}")

It doesn't seem to support multiple variables in one 'if' statement, hence the x_1 and x_2.

How do you intend to write complex roots in factored form?

Oh yeah, you’re right. Thanks though.

Be aware that when b^2 >> 4*a*c the root x_1 suffers from catastrophic cancellation and should instead be computed as  `c/(a*x_2). NB your code is not defended against the case where a == 0 (which will certainly happen if this is a CS programming exercise).

@MartinBrown Can you give an example of b^2 >> 4ac? Did you mean greater than or something else I'm yet to be clear on?

You're right, if a==0, then it's no longer quadratic. A more robust program would have to factor that in. I actually have a more robust program for solving and graphing quadratics on GitHub



in the mathematics sense of very much bigger than. Try eg, a = 1, b=10^8, c=1 so that `d  = sqrt(10^16-1) = 10^8 (due to FP double precision limitations). True roots in double precision are 10^8 and 10^-8. Your code will give zero for the smaller one.



Thanks for pointing that out, I'll have a look.
